# i have a problem in switch case *javascript

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

```
var id = e.target.id;

switch (id) {
    case "ow":
        console.log("ow");
    break;
    case "r6s":
        console.log("r6s");
    break;
    case "fortnite":
        console.log("fortnite");
    break;
    case "rl":
        console.log("rl");
    break;
    case "programmer":
        console.log("programmer");
    break;
    case "designer":
        console.log("designer");
    break;
    case "editor":
        console.log("editor");
    break;
}
```

when i write this code my editor tell me this
http://prntscr.com/mkoe8g (Expected 'case' at column 5 not column 9.........)

- i can see the console.log just in firefox it didn't display in chrome and opera

Comment: you might just wanna do `console.log(id);` ...

Comment: your editor is wrong - may be it throw this warrning due to number of spaces before case/console/break ?

Comment: So your linter is complaining about your indents

Comment: for me, the `break` should be indented.

Comment: @NinaScholz but does the ruleset for the linter agree? :)

Comment: I think there is nothing wrong on your code, u just check and change your compiler

Comment: @epascarello, who uses linters?

Comment: Not seeing the console.log in other browsers means it is not seeing the same id, means target may be different so we would need to see how the code is called and the HTML that goes with it.

Comment: @NinaScholz Guessing your organization does not have a programming standard for how code should look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have a problem. Thats a linter warning (it's yellow not red). It just means that someone told your IDE, that a case should be moved right by 5 spaces and not 9:

```
 switch(id) {
 case "ow": // "looks good"
       case "ow": // "looks bad to the ide"
```

However in my eyes that is just a matter of preference, both versions are readable, feel free to ignore that warning (or make your IDE relax a bit and choose different linting rules).

Answer (score 1):

Those are formatting warning, not errors.  Some formats prefer `case` not to be indented.  Example:

```
switch(x) {
case 1:
   break;
case 2:
   break;
}
```

Comment: `window.console` and `console` are identical.

Comment: then why it didn't work in chrome and opera just in firefox is it a cashe problem ?